# como insertar el value de un select en multiples columnas de una tabla en MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select, combobox

buen dia, ojalá me puedan apoyar con esta consulta, **¿como puedo insertar el value de un select(combobox) php en multiples columnas en una tabla en mysql dependiendo del dato seleccionado?**.

Por ejemplo tengo este formulario ligado a combobox anidados con datos obtenidos de una tabla, el ultimo select contiene 3 values: `peras, manzanas,naranjas`. como hago para que si selecciono naranjas me guarde el value en la columna `id_naranjas`, si selecciono `peras` en la columna `id_peras` y asi sucesivamente y posteriormente sumar la cantidad de registros de cada columna por persona.

Por ejemplo si Juan Pérez selecciono el díaa de hoy manzanas y el díaa de mañana tambien como puedo sumar esos registros del mismo id de participante referentes al valor seleccionado en este caso 2 manzanas.

Aquí está mi código funcional hasta ahora:

Esta es la base de datos mysql tabla frutas

```
id |id_ciudad |id_colonia |id_participante |id_fruta
```

me gustaria que quedara algo así:

```
id |id_ciudad |id_colonia |id_participante |id_peras |id_manzanas |id_naranjas
```

---

**index.php**

```
<div class="container">

<h1>
Seleccionar Participante
</h1>

<form id="frm-Participante" action="procesar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id_jugador"  />

<?php
//Include database configuration file

//Get all country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ciudades ORDER BY nombre_ciudad ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ciudad</label>
<select name="id_ciudad" id="Ciudad" class="form-control" >
    <option value="">Seleccione la Ciudad</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id_ciudad'].'">'.$row['nombre_ciudad'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">no hay ciudades</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Colonia</label>
<select name="id_colonia" id="Colonia" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Seleccione la Colonia</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Participante</label>
<select name="id_participante" id="Participante" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Seleccione el Participante</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Eleccion del Participante</label>
    <select name="id_fruta" id="Fruta" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
        <option  value="1">Peras</option>
        <option  value="2">Manzanas</option>
        <option  value="3">Naranjas</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="upload-result text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>



</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm-Participante").submit(function(){
        return $(this).validate();
    });
});

    </script>
<script>


$('#Ciudad').change(function(){
$('#Colonia').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#Colonia').change(function(){
$('#Participante').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#Participante').change(function(){
$('#Fruta').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm-Participante").submit(function(){
        return $(this).validate();
    });
});

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Ciudad').on('change',function(){
    var CiudadID = $(this).val();
    if(CiudadID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'id_categoria='+CiudadID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Colonia').html(html);
                $('#Participante').html('<option value="">Seleccione el Colonia primero</option>')
                $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Colonia').html('<option value="">Seleccione Ciudad primero</option>');
        $('#Participante').html('<option value="">Seleccione Colonia primero</option>');
        $('#Colonia').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled');

    }
});

$('#Colonia').on('change',function(){
    var ColoniaID = $(this).val();
    if(ColoniaID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'id_colonia='+ColoniaID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#Participante').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#Colonia').html('<option value="">Seleccione Colonia primero</option>');
        $('#Participante').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#Fruta').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

---

**procesar.php**

```
<?php    
require_once'conexion.php';
include'funciones.php';

bd_agregar($_REQUEST);

//Cerramos conexión.
$cone->close();     
?>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**funciones.php**

```
<?php
require_once'conexion.php';

//Creamos función
function bd_agregar($temp){
//Especificamos variable global.
global $cone;

//Obtenemos datos formulario
$id_ciudad = $_REQUEST['id_ciudad'];
$id_colonia = $_REQUEST['id_colonia'];
$id_participante = $_REQUEST['id_participante'];
$id_fruta = $_REQUEST['id_fruta'];

//Insertamos datos
$cone->query("INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_fruta) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')");         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_jugador.$id_fruta;
}

//Comprobamos ejecución sentencia.
if ($cone===false) {
printf("Mensaje de error: %s\n", $cone->error);
} else {
echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente";
}
?>
```

**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frutas` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_ciudad` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_colonia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_participante` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`id_peras` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id_manzanas` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id_naranjas` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo y apoyo.

[image: adjunto la estructura de la tabla]

Answer (score 1):

puedes agregar una condicional Switch o IF para validar el valor obtenido antes de insertarlo en la base de datos.

Pero antes deberías tener los columnas creadas en tu tabla con NOT NULL.

Ejemplo:

Index.php  con valores en cadena y no numéricos

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Eleccion del Participante</label>
    <select name="id_fruta" id="Fruta" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
        <option  value="peras">Peras</option>
        <option  value="manzanas">Manzanas</option>
        <option  value="naranjas">Naranjas</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

funciones.php

```
$id_fruta = $_REQUEST['id_fruta'];

swtich( $id_fruta ) {

    case 'peras':
        // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_peras
        $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_peras) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
        break;
    case 'manzanas':
        // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_manzanas
        $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_manzanas) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
        break;
    case 'naranjas':
        // Creas una variable que guarde la consulta con el nombre de columna id_naranjas
        $sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_naranjas) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Valor erróneo"; die;

}

// Pasamos la varriable $sql
$cone->query( $sql );         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_jugador.$id_fruta;
}
```

Y esta es otra manera un poco más fácil pero puede no ser tan segura pero se puede utilizar

Al obtener la variable, colocarla directamente en la variable de consulta `$sql` junto con el texto `id_{$id_frutas}`.

Ejemplo:

```
$id_fruta = $_REQUEST['id_fruta'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO frutas (id_ciudad,id_colonia,id_participante,id_{$id_fruta}) VALUES ('$id_ciudad','$id_colonia','$id_participante','$id_fruta')";

// Pasamos la varriable $sql
$cone->query( $sql );         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_jugador.$id_fruta;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder mi pregunta, lo que planteas suena bastante logico, solo que tengo algunos problemas, el codigo se ejecuta sin problemas y si me aparecen los datos de registro que se obtienen de los combobox justo el resultado de esta peticion               
  $cone->query( $sql );         
  echo $id_ciudad.$id_colonia.$id_jugador.$id_fruta;   pero no se guardan en la tabla de la db, a que se debera? de antemanno muchas gracias

Comment: Vez al PHPMyAdmin y tomale una captura de pantalla a la estructura de la tabla, para poder ayudarte un poco mejor. Cuando seleccionas una tabla para ver los valores, en la parte superior hay un menú y entre ellos hay uno que dice Estructura.

Comment: ya agregue la captura en la parte de arriba, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Hola, veo que en la columna `Nulo` dice **No**, es por eso que no te guarda, debe decir **SI**, porque en el método `$cone->query()` no le pasas valores a algunas columnas como al de peras, manzanas o naranjas y eso hace que no te lo guarde, porque no acepta que no le pasen valores y al aceptar valores **Nulos**, al no establecer la columna a guardar, MySQL le colocará automáticamente `NULL` y te lo guardará correctamente.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver con lo que me comentas muchas gracias por el apoyo, tengo otra consulta ojala me puedas apoyar, los valores obtenidos registrados en cada columna como los puedo sumar por id de participante? por ejemplo si juan perez el dia de hoy eligio manzana y mañana tambien manzana como puedo sumar que juan perez lleva 2 manzanas etc. gracias por el apoyo